# How to create a durable topic in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am new to kafka and am still learning the basics of the same. I want to create a durable topic which is preserved even after the zoopkeeper and/or kafka server shutdown.
What I notice it this - I have a zookeeper and kafka server running on my local macbook. When I shutdown the zookeeper server and again bring it up quickly I can see the previously created topics. But If I restart the system and then restart the zookeeper server - I dont see the topic that I had created earlier.
I am running kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1 on my local system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because `/tmp` is getting cleaned after reboot resulting in loss of your data.

To fix this modify your Zookeeper `dataDir` property (in `config/zookeeper.properties`) and Kafka `log.dirs` (in `config/server.properties`) to be somewhere NOT in `/tmp`.